# How to visualize TensorFlow graph without running train/evaluate with estimator API?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

How can I visualize the graph on TensorBoard using the Estimator API of TensorFlow without running training or evaluation?

I know how it is achieved with the session API when you have access to the Graph object, but could not find anything for the Estimator API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimators create and manage `tf.Graph` and `tf.Session` objects for you. These objects are therefore not easily accessible. Please note that, by default, the graph is exported inside the events file when you call `estimator.train`.

What you can do however, is call your `model_function` outside of `tf.estimator` and then use the classic `tf.summary.FileWriter()` to export the graph.

Here is a code snippet with a very simple estimator that just applies a dense layer to the input:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Basic input_fn
def input_fn(x, y, batch_size=4):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size).repeat(1)
    return dataset

# Basic model_fn that just apply a dense layer to an input
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

    y = tf.layers.dense(features, 1)

    increment_global_step = tf.assign_add(global_step, 1)

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode,
            predictions={'preds':y},
            loss=tf.constant(0.0, tf.float32),
            train_op=increment_global_step)

# Fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=[10, 100])
y = np.random.normal(size=[10])

# Just to show that the estimator works
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
estimator.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(x, y), steps=1)


# Classic way of exporting the graph using placeholders and an outside call to the model_fn
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    # Placeholders
    features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, x.shape)
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, y.shape)

    # Creates the graph
    _ = model_fn(features, labels, None)

    # Export the graph to ./graph
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./graph', sess.graph)
```

Comment: The main reason I asked this question was to see how distribution strategy works in tensorflow. I went through the distribution strategy code (mirrored strategy) but could not understad how tensorflow does the all reduce operation. I was wondering if they add ops in the graph to do all reduce. I do not have a GPU device, so could not run the actual MNIST model with distributed strategy. But I have my answer, I do need the graph and session objects to be able to display the graph on tensorboard.

Answer (score 1):

To be able visualize the graph with the TensorBoard you must have it in the events file. If during the training you instantiate the writer with the session graph:

```
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.summaries_dir + '/train', sess.graph)
```

you should have it.

Given that, just call tensorboard and provide it the path where the events file is stored:

```
tensorboard --logdir=path/to/log-directory
```

and open the Graph tab.

Comment: You don't easily have access to both the Session and the Graph when using the Tf.Estimator API.